# Finding parallel / covering elements in QGIS

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, qgis

I have three network`s in QGIS.  The third network is a combination of two.

I want to find unmapped items on network. How I can found only parallel /covering elements? Perpendicular elements are unnecessary and make finding gaps difficult. I tried to subtract unconnected items from connected, but there is too much data.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the table structure and a data sample, so that we can better understand your question.

Comment: It's unclear what ypur goal is exactly; merge those networks properly? an example would help a lot indeed. also, this is a lot better suited on the [gis.se] board. you're welcome to join us there...